# Integer factiorization function somewhere in Haskell library?

Tags: function, math, haskell, integer

I find some library with implementation of integer factorization function. Preferably some fast implementation in some popular library, to not reinvent the wheel.

Is there some ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick google search shows [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) package by Daniel Fischer.

Comment: Arithmoi is great.  Not only does it contain lots of number-theoretical tools, but it also implements them properly and gets near GMP speeds.

Comment: It is not tests covered, not very good for me ...

Comment: @s9gf4ult: You will find it more helpful to give constraints in your question, rather than after an answer has been provided.

Comment: It has a rather elaborate 'certification' infrastructure. It might help if you were clearer what you want.

Answer (score 2):

See [`primeFactors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primes/0.2.1.0/doc/html/Data-Numbers-Primes.html#v%3aprimeFactors) in [primes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes-0.2.1.0). It's reasonably fast, for example it factors `104729 * 104723` instantly.

Comment: Note that `104729 * 104723` can be deduced from a simple square root test and some linear probing. A better factorization litmus test would involve primes which are farther apart, but not too close to `1`. Consider `104729 * 88801`